# Get sum / mean in purrr over data.frame subset

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, purrr

I would like to find the sum across occurrences and then the mean of those sums across simulations in the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

s <- 2

data <- data.frame(
lamda = c(5, 2, 3),
meanlog = c(9, 10, 11), 
sdlog = c(2, 2.1, 2.2))


    data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(freq = map(lamda, ~rpois(s, .x)),
         freqsev = map(freq, ~map(.x, function(k) rlnorm(k, meanlog, sdlog))))
```

I would like to take the sum of freqsev then the mean of the sum of freqsev over the simulation (s) dimension:
Any ideas on how  this can be achieved? Thank you!

```
data3 <- data2 %>% 
  mutate(sum-freqsev = ???
         mean-sum-freqsev = ???)
```

**Dimensions expected:**

`data2` is a data.frame with 3 rows (e.g . per `lamda`)

`sum-freqsev` should be list of `<int [2]>` i.e the sum of entries in `freqsev`.
`mean-sum-freqsev` should be a number, simply the mean of `sum-freqsev` per `lamda`

Comment: What is your expected output? Should `mean-sum-freqsev` be one number per row or just one number?

Comment: @avid_useR please see my update on dimensions expected; `mean-sum-freqsev` should be a number per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a nested `map` to find `sum_freqsev` and a single `map` to find `mean_sum_freqsev`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data3 <- data2 %>% 
  mutate(sum_freqsev = freqsev %>% map(~map_dbl(., sum)),
         mean_sum_freqsev = sum_freqsev %>% map_dbl(mean),
         percentile = freqsev %>% map(~map(., ~quantile(.x, c(.50, .90)))))
```

The inner `map_dbl` sums the entries of `freqsev` over each simulation and returns a vector of type double instead of a list with two elements.

`mean_sum_freqsev` is calculated by taking the `mean` of each list element (a vector) of `sum_freqsev` and returning a double.

**Output:**

```
> as.tibble(data3)
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  lamda meanlog sdlog freq      freqsev    sum_freqsev mean_sum_freqsev percentile
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <list>    <list>     <list>                 <dbl> <list>    
1     5       9   2   <int [2]> <list [2]> <dbl [2]>           1493880. <list [2]>
2     2      10   2.1 <int [2]> <list [2]> <dbl [2]>            623586. <list [2]>
3     3      11   2.2 <int [2]> <list [2]> <dbl [2]>             15219. <list [2]>

> data3 %>% pull(percentile)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
      50%       90% 
  24633.8 1832533.5 

[[1]][[2]]
      50%       90% 
 22461.18 114075.74 

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
     50%      90% 
470808.0 845321.7 

[[2]][[2]]
      50%       90% 
 12539.82 202665.48 

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
      50%       90% 
 3906.931 10100.830 

[[3]][[2]]
50% 90% 
 NA  NA
```

Comment: That's excellent, @avid_useR ! I'd like to add percentiles too but putting `percentile = freqsev %>% map(~map_dbl(., quantile(c(.50, .90))))` in the mutate function  does not seem to be working...

Comment: @VincentRisington `quantile(x, c(.50, .90))` returns two numbers, so applying that to each vector in `<list [2]>` of `freqsev` yields a vector of two for each `<list [2]>`. You therefore cannot coerce it to a `dbl`. See my update.

Comment: Thanks @avid_useR, that's great. How could I coerce this so that the percentile field is `<list [2]>` per lamda, i.e. the first item is percentile = 0.5 and the second is percentile = 0.9? Much appreciated.

Comment: @VincentRisington You have two simulations for each `lamda`, so you will get two numbers for each simulation. The way that you propose would mean only showing the 50th percentile for the first simulation and only the 90th percentile for the second simulation. Is that what you want?

Comment: if I set `s <- 10` then the percentile field type is `<list [10]>` - so I'm not entirely sure if the percentile function is getting applied. Shouldn't it be the same length as the percentile list defined?

Comment: Sorry, I realized that `sum_freqsev ` should be a sum of `freqsev`over the `freq` occurrences, not over simulation. Then `mean_sum_freqsev` is actually taking the mean of the simulations i.e. the simulated mean. `percentile` should work in the same way as mean by taking the percentile over simulations (with the added dimension of the list of percentiles).

Comment: @VincentRisington "`sum_freqsev` should be a sum of `freqsev` over the `freq` occurrences, not over simulation" Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "over the `freq` occurrences". So am I still adding up all the numbers in each simulation in `freqsev`?